# Transfer Data from Data Grid View to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable

May I know what is the easiest way to transfer data from data grid view to data table? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully then come back with your question

Comment: Not using an unbound DataGridView. If you want to get user Data by DataGridView simply put a predefined DataTable under the DataGridView and then take it as soon as you got all information. Data put into the DataGridView will be inserted into the DataTable as soon as the DataGridView contains it.